# How to implement AOS in React AOS Doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, particles.js, aos.js

AOS Conflict with ParticleJS with `react-tsparticles`

### This is:

- Bug

### Specifications

- AOS version:  ^2.3.4
- OS: Windows 10
- Browser: Chrome

### Expected Behavior

AOSing

### Actual Behavior

Particle.js Conflict with AOS

### Steps to Reproduce the Problem

`<Particles/>` is component made from react-tsparticles . if this component is a parent or sibling aos doesnt work.

```
           <div>
              <Particles />
            <h1 data-aos="fade-up"></h1>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Possible Solution

for now you can work around this

```
   <div>
         <div>
              <Particles />
          </div>
          <h1 data-aos="fade-up"></h1>
</div>
```